# put 2 labels into the middle of a jframe border layout

Tags: java, swing, jlabel, layout-manager, border-layout

My java code produces a label in the middle with a button on the top and bottom. I want the code below to produce something that looks like this.

[image]

I just don't know how to add 2 labels to the center with this code  f.add(b2,BorderLayout.CENTER);  . Because it seems like only one item can be in the center. My code wants both labels to be symmetrical that are in the center.

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.io.IOException;
import javax.swing.*;

public class may2 {
    Frame f;  
    JLabel b2=new JLabel("");;  

    may2() throws IOException{ 
        f=new JFrame();  
        JButton b1 = new JButton("First");
        JButton b3 = new JButton("Second");
        f.add(b1,BorderLayout.NORTH); 
        f.add(b2,BorderLayout.CENTER);  
        f.add(b3,BorderLayout.SOUTH); 
        f.setSize(400,500);  
        f.setVisible(true);  
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {  
        new may2();  
    }  

}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The key: nest JPanels, each using its own layout manager.

Create a JPanel and give it a `new GridLayout(1, 0)` for 1 row, variable number of columns. Add your JLabels to this JPanel and then add this JPanel into the BorderLayout.CENTER position of the main container, the one using BorderLayout.

e.g.,

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.io.IOException;
import javax.swing.*;

public class May2b {
    Frame f;  
    JLabel label1 = new JLabel("Label 1");  
    JLabel label2 = new JLabel("Label 2");  

    May2b() throws IOException{ 
        JPanel centerPanel = new JPanel(new GridLayout(1, 0));
        centerPanel.add(label1);
        centerPanel.add(label2);

        f = new JFrame();  
        JButton b1 = new JButton("First");
        JButton b3 = new JButton("Second");
        f.add(b1,BorderLayout.NORTH); 
        f.add(centerPanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);  
        f.add(b3,BorderLayout.SOUTH); 

        f.pack();
        // f.setSize(400,500);  

        f.setVisible(true);  
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {  
        new May2b();  
    }  
}
```

Also:

- Class names should begin with an upper-case letter to follow Java conventions. This will make it easier for others to read your code.
- Avoid setting a JPanel's size and instead call `pack()` on it after adding all components and before setting it visible. This will tell the layout managers and the components to re-size components as per their preferred sizes.

Comment: *for 1 row, 2 columns.* - actually that is for one row (try adding a 3rd component). It only ever makes sense to enter either the desired row or column (the other value should be 0). If you enter both, then the row value is used.

Comment: @camickr: thank you for that information. I have edited the answer to reflect what you have said.